# Youtube video in laravel

Tags: laravel, youtube

I'm using Laravel Video Embed(https://github.com/Merujan99/laravel-video-embed) so i can get the embeded code from a youtube url.It works just fine but i want to know is there any possibility to change the width and height properties of the embeded video in the view ? 
my code in the controller:

```
public static function getvideo($id)

{
  $url = Blog::where('id',$id)->value('video_link');
  return LaravelVideoEmbed::parse($url);
}
```

my view:

```
<div>
 {!!App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::getvideo($blog->id)!!}
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried the obvious? (CSS styling)

Comment: of course i did no luck . the  properties of the iframe by default are width="480" height="295" any solution to change them ?

Comment: Post the code into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass attributes to the embed like so:

```
$params = [];

$attributes = [
  'height' => 100px,
  'width' => 200px,
];

LaravelVideoEmbed::parse($url, ['YouTube'], $params, $attributes)
```

Which will work dynamically.

Comment: thank you very much it worked perfectly !!! i just changed the attributes to this: 'height' => '300',
        'width' => '750',

Comment: No Problem, Glad to help.